# What are the various ways to write querystring?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, querystringparameter

Just for curiosity, i want to know i how many ways we can write the parameters in a querystring. I have encountered the following

- **&**  (is common that we use in our most of the application)
- **,** (in some banking application)
- **;**  (bank.co.in/BANKAWAYTRAN;jsessionid, this is from my banks QS   :-) )

Could you please explain more about the querystring and the parameter separation symbols.

Comment: The third example does not have a querystring, querystring is what comes after '?'.

Comment: actually my entire url was ;jsessionid=AlkiUgdgd5#gjasdfFAusSSukSu$$dkasd - that somewhat base64 encrypted string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it just about any way you wanted. Your code simply has to interpret them in a meaningful way.